# Making .py file to .exe with kivy but Spec file not found

Tags: python, kivy

So I have created an app with python and kivy and wanted to make it into an .exe file. I was following a tutorial but when going into the .spec file I imported the **sdl2 and gstream** but then an error occured. **I believe that I fixed it by downloading them.**

But a new error came out saying `Spec file "Autoclicker.spec" not found!` I have been looking for answers for awhile but I can't find anything. Be awesome if you could help :D

I re-downloaded the kivy dependencies that I forgot when first getting kivy. I also looked through numerous tutorials but none worked.

Comment: as I know `spec` can be special file in `pyinstaller` which you can create on your own. It is information for `pyinstaller` what modules you want add to `exe`

Comment: kivy documentation for [Create a package for Windows](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/packaging-windows.html) mentions `spec` file. You have to use `Ctr+F` to search in text.

Comment: pyinstaller documentation: [Using Spec Files](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/spec-files.html)

Answer (score 0):

To compile your Kivy app, I suggest you use the Python library `Pyinstaller`.

To install it, type `pip install pyinstaller` in your terminal.

The next step is to create a `.spec` file and a version file that will provide your app information to Pyinstaller. Here is a spec file template for a Kivy application:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-
from kivy_deps import sdl2, glew
from kivy.tools.packaging.pyinstaller_hooks import get_deps_minimal, get_deps_all, hookspath, runtime_hooks

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(
    ['../your_main_file.py'],
    pathex=[],
    datas=[("../your_folder","your_folder"),("../your_file.ext",".")],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
    win_private_assemblies=False,
    cipher=block_cipher,
    hiddenimports=["tkinter"],
    noarchive=False
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data, cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          name='YourAppName',
          version="version.txt",
          *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)],
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=False,
          icon='../your_icon.ico')
```

The version file allows you to configure the manifest of your future application by specifying the application version and other information. Here is a template of a version file:

```
# UTF-8
#
# For more details about fixed file info 'ffi' see:
# http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646997.aspx
VSVersionInfo(
  ffi=FixedFileInfo(
# filevers and prodvers should be always a tuple with four items: (1, 2, 3, 4)
# Set not needed items to zero 0.
filevers=(1, 0, 0, 0),
prodvers=(1, 0, 0, 0),
# Contains a bitmask that specifies the valid bits 'flags'r
mask=0x3f,
# Contains a bitmask that specifies the Boolean attributes of the file.
flags=0x0,
# The operating system for which this file was designed.
# 0x4 - NT and there is no need to change it.
OS=0x4,
# The general type of file.
# 0x1 - the file is an application.
fileType=0x1,
# The function of the file.
# 0x0 - the function is not defined for this fileType
subtype=0x0,
# Creation date and time stamp.
date=(0, 0)
),
  kids=[
StringFileInfo(
  [
  StringTable(
    u'040904B0',
    [StringStruct(u'CompanyName', u'Your company name'),
    StringStruct(u'FileDescription', u'Your Filename'),
    StringStruct(u'FileVersion', u'Your version number'),
    StringStruct(u'InternalName', u'Your app name'),
    StringStruct(u'LegalCopyright', u'Copyright (c) your company name'),
    StringStruct(u'OriginalFilename', u'YourApp.exe'),
    StringStruct(u'ProductName', u'YourApp'),
    StringStruct(u'ProductVersion', u'4.2.0')])
  ]),
VarFileInfo([VarStruct(u'Translation', [1033, 1200])]) 
  ]
)
```

Once everything is filled, you can compile your application with the command :

```bash
pyinstaller your_spec_file.spec
```

The **sdl2** and **gstream** dependencies will automatically be bundled during the compilation.